# Error in use of stored procedure In Entity Framwork?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want use this stored procedure in Entity Framework

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[GetSood]
   @datefrom nvarchar(15),
  @dateto nvarchar(15)
AS 
    SELECT Price, Numbers, PriceTotal 
    FROM VW_Sale  
    WHERE DateCreate >= @datefrom 
      AND DateCreate <= @dateto  
      AND IsSale = 1 
      AND PayType = 2;
```

I add this procedure in the model but when run show this error

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified
>   'AriaSalesmanagmentModel.VW_Sale'. A member of the type, 'ID', does
>   not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

and my code is:

```
public List<DAL.VW_Sale> GetSood(string dateFrom, string dateTo)
{
   DAL.AriaSalestEntities objAria = new AriaSalestEntities();

   var sood = from s in objAria.GetSood(dateFrom, dateTo) select s;
   return sood.ToList();
}
```

please help me?

Comment: It's store**D** procedure - as in STORED inside SQL Server - **not** store procedure (has nothing to do with a store....)

Answer (score 0):

If your entity is based on all the columns in VW_Sale, then you need to have `SELECT * FROM VW_Sale`

I would also recommend you not pass dates as strings - and certainly not as nvarchar.